# How do I detect what application generated a specific core dump on OS X?

Tags: macos, coredump

I want to detect what application generated a core dump on OS X.

How can I find this information? Runing `file core.1234` does not give the application name, online something like `Mach-O 64-bit core x86_64`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use `otool`:

```
$ otool -c core.1234
```

for more, see [man page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/otool.1.html). More magics can be found in this fantastic document [Mac OS X debugging magic](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/technotes/tn2004/tn2124.html#SECCOREDUMPS).

Comment: Sorry but this looks borken, here is the output: `Argument strings on the stack at: 00007fff5fc00000
load command 173 size not a multiple of 8
load command 174 size not a multiple of 8
load command 175 size not a multiple of 8
load command 176 size not a multiple of 8
`

Comment: There is nothing from with the core file, i checked with others and had the same result. And thanks, the doc you linked to seams really interesting.