# How do I get a core dump on OS X Lion?

Tags: postgresql, segmentation-fault, osx-lion, coredump, ulimit

I am working on a PostgreSQL extension in C that segfaults, so I want to look at the core dump file on my OS X Lion box. However, there are no core files in `/cores` or anywhere else that I can find. It appears that they are enabled in the system but are limited to a size of 0:

```
> sysctl kern.coredump               
kern.coredump: 1
> ulimit -c
0
```

I tried setting `ulimit -c unlimited` in the shell session I'm using to start and stop PostgreSQL, and it seems to stick:

```
> ulimit -c
unlimited
```

And yet no matter what I do, no core files. I am starting PostgreSQL with `pg_ctl -c`, where the `-c` tells PostgreSQL to generate core dumps. But the system has nothing. How can I get Lion to dump core files?

Comment: If I write a tiny program that just calls abort(), set ulimit -c unlimited, and run it, I get a core dump in /cores on Lion. Can you do that as a quick sanity-check? If it works, I'd suspect something odd is going on in PostgreSQL, or something is getting in the way between your ulimit and the eventual child process kicked off by pg_ctl.

Answer (score 1):

The /cores/ directory is not necessarily there in Lion , and if it's not there, you won't get cores.  You should be able to set the ulimit (as you have), run a program like cat(1), quit with a SIGQUIT (control-backslash) and get a coredump:

lion:~ user$ ulimit -c unlimited
lion:~ user$ cat
^\
^\
Quit: 3 (core dumped)
lion:~ user$ ls -l /cores/
total 716584
-r--------  1 user  user  366891008 Jun 21 23:35 core.1263
lion:~ user$

Technical Note TN2124 http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#technotes/tn2124/ as suggested by Yuji in https://stackoverflow.com/a/3783403/225077 is helpful.